# What's a "nice" way of stopping a (linear) runnable in case of activity switch?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I have a thread that will do some processing, then has runnable code which will display the results on the screen. The issue is that if the user presses the back arrow while the runnable is between two lines of display code, the next line will crash as the activity no longer exists.

The below code accomplishes the goal, but I hate having `if` statements before each line. Is there a better way?

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    imgThread.interrupt();
}

private void processImage(){
        final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("TEXT");
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.show();

        imgThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Process the image a bit

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!imgThread.isInterrupted())
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(mDisplayBitmap);
                        if(!imgThread.isInterrupted())
                        progress.setMessage("TEXT TEXT");
                        if(!imgThread.isInterrupted())
                        progress.show();
                    }
                });

                //More processing

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!imgThread.isInterrupted())
                        addScreenListener();
                        if(!imgThread.isInterrupted())
                        determineHelpToast("TEXT TEXT TEXT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        if(!imgThread.isInterrupted())
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }
        }; imgThread.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really safe way to do this is to modify your Runnable so that it never references the Android Context (Activity, etc.).

The easiest way to do this is to communicate changes to the Activity via an event bus.